# iOS 11. Landscape mode for UITableView in IPhoneX

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, landscape, iphone-x

Could anyone explain how to fix section titles and headers in UITableView for IPhoneX in landscape?

I use simple methods sectionIndexTitlesForTableView and titleForHeaderInSection, but the section titles and headers placed in wrong place for IPhoneX.

[image]
[image]

The cells is fine.

Comment: set constraint to safe area in storyboard. if you are doing programmatically use safeanchor for left and right

Answer (score 0):

For **sectionIndexTitlesForTableView** wrong placement would occur only if you set the **contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior** of Scrollview to **UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever**